# How to call a "div id" from a href tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I have code like this, I want to show the `detailMess` after confirmed. So, how can I call `div-id` inside an  a-href:

```
 <a href="" onclick="return confirm('1 time count if you click OK, Are you sure?');">Show contact details</a>

        <div id="detailMess" style="display: none;">
        
            <%  
                string uID = "-1";
                var u = Membership.GetUser();
                if (u != null) { uID = u.ProviderUserKey.ToString(); }
                string U1 = Convert.ToString(Model.Load.OwnerId) ?? "";
                bool isOwner = uID.Equals(U1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
            %>
            <% if ((!LDC.Common.isShowLetGoContactInfor) || (User.IsInRole("Staff")) || (isOwner))
               {  %>
            <%
                if (Model.User != null && Model.User.Profiles == null) { Model.User.Profiles = new LDC.Domain.Profile(); }
                Html.RenderPartial("ContactInfo", Model);
            %>
            <% }
               else
               { %>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("LetgoContactInfo"); %>
            <%} %>
        </div>
```

Somebody help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

`<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('detailMess').show()">click</a>`

I think it will work.

Comment: I want at first load client have to click and confirm to view, if yes -> load div

Comment: Pandian's answer will do it

Answer (score 0):

hi try the below code it will help you...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function check()
{
    if(confirm("1 time count if you click OK, Are you sure?"))
    document.getElementById("sam").style.display="";
    else
    document.getElementById("sam").style.display="none";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick='check()'>check</a>
    <div class="Sam" id="sam">Hi You are here now</div>
</body>
</html>
```